# r: running all dataframes through function to get min and max date

Tags: r, function

I have two dataframes, `df1` & `df2`, which each have a distinct `Date` column (named the same with same case).

I created a function to tell me the *min* and *max* dates when I run each dataframe through it:

```
dMMfunc<- function(df){
  maxDate<- max(df[['Date']])
  minDate<- min(df[['Date']])
  return(c(maxDate, minDate))
}

> dMMfunc(df1)
[1] "2017-11-26" "2017-11-20"
```

I then created a list of the dataframes to pass through my function, getting a read on the min and max of each, but it throws and error see below:

```
dfList<- c(df1, df2)
> lapply(dfList, dMMfunc)
Error in df[["Date"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How do I get my function to return the *min* and *max* `Date` of each dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need `list` instead of `c`

```
dfList <- list(df1, df2)
```

The difference is that `c` concatenates the columns of the second dataset to the first and returns a `list` of `vector`s instead of a `list` of `data.frame`, e.g.

```
c(mtcars, iris)
```

and

```
list(mtcars, iris)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() - 1:5)
```

Comment: This work and now that I've seen it run I have one question: is it possible to populate in the function which min/max dates correspond to which dataframe?

Comment: @enriqueStateSpacias  You can create a named list and then use `imap` to create the column that gives an identifier of the object name.  `library(tidyverse); imap_dfr(mget(paste0('df', 1:2)), ~tibble(data = .y, minmax = dMMfunc(.)))`